# Neo4j fails to start up due to trigger execution failure

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I have a triggered called `create-owner-notification`. It worked like a charm after creating it, but after a restart of Neo4j it blocks a successful start up of the database. The error found in `debug.log` is:

```
[a.t.Trigger] Error executing trigger create-owner-notification in phase before Unknown function 'apoc.create.uuid' (line 5, column 83 (offset: 193))
"MERGE (o)<-[:RELATES_TO]-(n:Notification:OwnerNotification{date_created: dt, uid: apoc.create.uuid()})<-[:HAS_NOTIFICATION{read: false, date_received: dt}]-(u)"
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.query.QueryExecutionKernelException.asUserException(QueryExecutionKernelException.java:35)
[..]
```

As can be seen it doesn't recognise the function `apoc.create.uuid`.

My first idea was to simply remove the `apoc.create.uuid` dependency and instead call the native `randomUUID()` function instead. However, there is no way I can modify or remove the current trigger, for the database cannot start. If I set the config value `apoc_trigger_enabled` to `false` the database does start successfully but I cannot interact with the trigger in order to remove it.

If need be I can share further logging or config files.

How can I get the database to startup and successfully get the trigger to work again?